# string replacement in Ruby: greentexting support for imageboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to have greentext support for my Rails imageboard (though it should be mentioned that this is strictly a Ruby problem, not a Rails problem)

basically, what my code does is:
1. chop up a post, line by line
2. look at the first character of each line. if it's a ">", start the greentexting
3. at the end of the line, close the greentexting
4. piece the lines back together

My code looks like this:

```
def filter_comment(c) #use for both OP's and comments

c1 = c.content

str1 = '<p class = "unkfunc">' #open greentext
str2 = '</p>' #close greentext

if c1 != nil
arr_lines = c1.split('\n') #split the text into lines

arr_lines.each do |a|
  if a[0] == ">"
    a.insert(0, str1) #add the greentext tag
    a << str2 #close the greentext tag

  end
end

c1 = ""

arr_lines.each do |a|
  strtmp = '\n'
  if arr_lines.index(a) == (arr_lines.size - 1) #recombine the lines into text
    strtmp = ""
  end
  c1 += a + strtmp
end


c2 = c1.gsub("\n", '<br/>').html_safe

end
```

But for some reason, it isn't working! I'm having weird things where greentexting only works on the first line, and if you have greentext on the first line, normal text doesn't work on the second line!

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: can provide an example what you are trying to achieve as a end result from what input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies with the spliting the lines in array.

```
   names = "Alice \n Bob \n Eve"
   names_a = names.split('\n')
   => ["Alice \n Bob \n Eve"]
```

Note the the string was not splited when \n was encountered.

Now lets try this

```
  names = "Alice \n Bob \n Eve"
  names_a = names.split(/\n/)
  => ["Alice ", " Bob ", " Eve"]
```

or This "\n" in double quotes. (thanks to Eric's Comment)

```
  names = "Alice \n Bob \n Eve"
  names_a = names.split("\n")
  => ["Alice ", " Bob ", " Eve"]
```

This  got split in array. now you can check and append the data you want

May be this is what you want.

```
def filter_comment(c) #use for both OP's and comments

c1 = c.content

str1 = '<p class = "unkfunc">' #open greentext
str2 = '</p>' #close greentext

if c1 != nil
arr_lines = c1.split(/\n/) #split the text into lines

arr_lines.each do |a|
  if a[0] == ">"
    a.insert(0, str1) #add the greentext tag 
     # Use a.insert id you want the existing ">" appended to it <p class = "unkfunc">>
     # Or else just assign a[0] = str1 
    a << str2 #close the greentext tag

  end
end

c1 = arr_lines.join('<br/>')
c2 = c1.html_safe  

end
```

Hope this helps..!!

Answer (score 1):

Side note, may be your problem, without getting too in depth...

Try joining your array back together with join()

```
c1 = arr_lines.join('\n')
```

Comment: or in your case, c1 = arr_lines.join('<br />')

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that your problem is with your CSS (or maybe HTML), not the Ruby. Did the resulting HTML look correct to you?

Comment: I think it's a Ruby code problem. the HTML was mishmashed in the wrong places. properly, the greentext would look like "<p class = "unkfunc">>implying</p>" but the tags were placed wrongly when the Ruby did its stuff.